# Changing colour in Markdown <mark> tag

Tags: html, css

I currently discovered the markdown  element, which lets me mark some text

```
<mark>Marked text</mark>
```

This results in this very nice looking pdf-text:

[image]

But how do I change the colour from it's default yellow to another colour?

Comment: hi, have you had problems appling the code to you project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i would suggest something like this (using inline css). Note that i used `!important` because in some browsers it may be necessary to force the process.

```html
<mark style="background: #00ced1!important">Marked text</mark>
```

alternatively, something like this (using external css).

```css
mark {background: red!important}
```

```html
<mark>Marked text</mark>
```

in this case the property is applied to **all the mark tags** in the webpage.
While this method works and is absolutely legitimate, it would be better, and more conventional, to use a css property like this:

```html
<p>this is a pretty paragraph with some <span style="background: blue">marked text</span></p>
```

hope this helped :)

Comment: This does not seem to work on Github. It does work for me in other `.md` browsers, however.

Answer (score 2):

The [mark](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/mark) tag is not for Markdown, but to mark or highlight text for notation purposes. It essentially is used to make text appear to have been highlighted with a highlighter, which explains the yellow background. Using the inspect tool in my browser, I see that the default styles for `mark` are:

```css
mark {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black;
}
```

So, to change the color, define some CSS. For example:

```css
mark {
  background-color: GreenYellow;
}
```

Comment: Adding this in my markdown file, and changing colours does not seem to have any effect

Comment: Wow! Until now, I didn't know there's a such thing as `GreenYellow` CSS color...

Comment: You need to define that in you CSS file. If you want to define the style in the body of your document, the other answer provides multiple ways to do so.

Answer (score 2):

You can write

```html
<mark style="background-color:burlywood;">Marked text</mark>
```

You can replace `"burlywood"` to any color of your choice.